# Generate a valid_from and valid_to date from one date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

I have a table (Sybase IQ) that contains data for different customers and their customer value from a certain point of time:

Old Customer Value Table:

```
customer_id | load_date   | customer_value
5           |  2016-01-01 | Basic
5           |  2016-04-01 | Premium
5           |  2016-08-01 | Gold
6           |  2016-01-01 | Basic
6           |  2016-04-01 | Premium
6           |  2016-08-01 | Gold
7           |  2016-01-01 | Basic
7           |  2016-04-01 | Premium
7           |  2016-08-01 | Gold
```

To join this table with other tables I have to know what was the valid customer_value for a customer in a specific timeframe.
So the idea was to transform the above table and create a new table with the following form.:

New Customer Value Table To Create

```
customer_id | date_valid_from | date_valid_to | customer_value
5           |  2016-01-01     | 2016-03-31    | Basic
5           |  2016-04-01     | 2016-08-24    | Premium
5           |  2016-08-25     | NULL          | Gold
6           |  2016-01-01     | 2016-03-31    | Basic
6           |  2016-04-01     | 2016-08-24    | Premium
6           |  2016-08-25     | NULL          | Gold
7           |  2016-01-01     | 2016-03-31    | Basic
7           |  2016-04-01     | 2016-08-24    | Premium
7           |  2016-08-25     | NULL          | Gold
```

Sadly I can't find any solution for an SQL query that creates me the desired output.

Comment: How to calculate the `date_valid_to` field? As there is no proper definition to calculate that in your question.

Comment: What is the sql server version? if it is sql server 2012 you can use windowing function lead/lag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lead` to get the date on the next row and subtract 1 day from it to get the end date of a period.

```
select customer_id,date_valid_from,
dateadd(day,-1,next_date) date_valid_to,customer_value 
from (
select 
customer_id,
load_date as date_valid_from,
lead(load_date) over(partition by customer_id order by load_date) as next_date,
customer_value 
from tablename
) x
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can query like this

```
select customer_id, load_date as datefrom, 
 dateto= dateadd(day, -1, lead(load_date) over(partition by customer_id order by customer_id, load_date)) , customer_value 
 from yourCustomer
```